# What is the Alternative for DirectionalShadowLight in LibGdx?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, 2d-games

I Have a 3D Model with Animations in LibGdx.

I Want to Create a Dynamic Shadow that Moves congruent with the Model.

I researched how to and found a lot about DirectionalShadowLight, but it seems to be not applicable anymore.

So What are the Other ways, or the Current Way to achieve this in LibGdx?

I've researched alternatives but nothing comes up.